# How to get chart as image without download it using anychart?

Tags: javascript, anychart, anychart-8.2

I'm a beginner with anychart library. 
I'm trying to get the chart as image and insert it inside a pdf.
I know that anychart has the following function to download the chart as pdf.

```
chart.saveAsPdf({"filename": id_container});
```

However I need to customize my pdf with jsPDF.

The method

```
chart.saveAsJpg({"filename": id_container});
```

automatically download the image. I'm using the 8.7.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the char image as base64 encoded string without downloading it. Check [the getJpgBase64String() function](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.Chart#getJpgBase64String).

Comment: How can I call it with width and height?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th function arguments are width and height. You can apply them like this:
```
  chart.getJpgBase64String(
    function (response) {
     var base64String = document.getElementById('getJpgBase64String');
     base64String.innerHTML = response;
   },
    function(err) {
     console.log(err);
   },
    600, 600);
```
The full description you can find in the API reference - https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.Chart#getJpgBase64String